# Emacs: Unable to load inf-ruby ("Wrong type argument: stringp, nil")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs

Whenever I try to run `inf-ruby` in emacs, it fails to load and I get the message "Wrong type argument: stringp, nil" in the echo area.

I have no idea how to go about debugging this, so the only solution I've tried is to restart the computer (which didn't work).

Could anyone offer advice on what is going wrong here/how to debug the error?

Edit: after enabling `(setq debug-on-error t)` and re-running `inf-ruby`, I got the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  expand-file-name(nil)
  byte-code("\305\306 \307\"! \n\310 \211 \2052 \f@ \311
!\203* r
q\210\305 ! \230\203) \312\303
\"\210)\fA\211 \204  \310+\207" [default-directory current-dir inf-ruby-buffers buffer --dolist-tail-- expand-file-name locate-dominating-file inf-ruby-console-match nil buffer-live-p throw] 5)
  inf-ruby-buffer()
  run-ruby("irb --prompt default --noreadline -r irb/completion" "ruby")
  inf-ruby("ruby")
  call-interactively(inf-ruby record nil)
  command-execute(inf-ruby record)
  helm-M-x(nil #("inf-ruby" 0 8 (match-part "inf-ruby")))
  call-interactively(helm-M-x nil nil)
  command-execute(helm-M-x)
```

Comment: You should enable `(setq debug-on-error t)` and post the backtrace

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question with the resulting debug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you started `inf-ruby` outside of an existing ruby-project (Gemfile). Recent versions of `inf-ruby` have a check for this condition:

https://github.com/nonsequitur/inf-ruby/commit/ec70d7f0e9d8d693d48e0cabfe55187e7b04e5f8

Upgrading your `inf-ruby` package should fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. My version was a day out of date :/

Comment: Probably not a big deal, but the reason this happened is the melpa-stable version of the `inf-ruby` package hasn't been updated. I've just installed the melpa version, and now I'm up and running.